# Shiny: how does it handle concurrent requests?

Tags: r, multithreading, shiny, multiprocessing, event-loop

If I start a Shiny application using

```sh
R -e 'shiny::runApp("/app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8888)'
```

how does it handle concurrent requests / what is its worker model?

Is each request handled in a different thread, process, does it use an event-loop model, or even, does it just handle them one at a time?

Comment: Its 1 thread, as R is single threaded. All sessions are connected via a websocket to that thread. Traditionally `shiny` reactive programming using traditional event loop model. There is a `flush cycle`, which does the following `receiving, updating, reacting, and sending` so while `reactives` or `observers` are updated its not possible to update other inputs. This is done to avoid race conditions

Comment: @PorkChop Feel free to write an answer!

Comment: [Here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/execution-scheduling.html) is a related article explaining shiny's event loop. [Here](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html) is another one regarding async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since R is single threaded so as the `shiny`, and its built on top of `node`
2. All sessions are connected via a `websocket` to that thread
3. Traditionally shiny reactive programming using standard `event loop model`
4. There is a concept of a `flush cycle`which does the following: `receiving, updating, reacting, and sending` so while `reactives` or `observers` are updated its not possible to update other inputs. This is done to avoid race conditions
5. You can take advantage of `async` programming within `shiny` by using [promises](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/index.html) package
6. If you want to integrate some of more advanced `js` libraries you can work with the [V8](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/index.html) package
7. You can also [integrate](https://resources.rstudio.com/rstudio-conf-2019/integrating-react-js-and-shiny) `react.js` with `shiny`